# How to include a menu template to all views

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I'm currently writing an extension for my site in which I use Joomla!
I'm now stuck on my info pages in which different kind of information about a movie is separated into different views/menus.
I thought about putting the templates all in the same folder and only using one **view.html.php** to have the minimum of duplicate code.
My structure looks like this:

[image]

I want the **default_menu.php** to be included in alle templates, that's why I thought that this would be the best practise.

But Joomla searches the folder with the name of the view that is called in the fronted. e.g. **www.site.net/com_component&view=car** would look for the folder **/views/car/** 
And that's the point where I'm stuck. How can I tell Joomla to look at one folder for different view names? And is this the best practice or Should I still separate the templates in different folders even though I would have a few **view.html.php** containing pretty much the same code? And of course I still have to include the menu in every template.

Comment: Unrelated question: What's that theme called?

Comment: Glacier - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Glacier